# Jupyter cell tag: "remove-input" has no effect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Here is my setup. I am expecting to only see the word "test" when I run the notebook, without the code cell. Am I understanding this functionality correctly?

```
# test.ipynb
print("test)
```

```
# In JupyterLab → Property Inspector → Cell Metadata
{
    "collapsed": true,
    "jupyter": {
        "outputs_hidden": true
    },
    "tags": [
        "remove-input",
    ]
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand these kind of tags (there are differences in naming) work with nbconvert, Sphinx and MyST-NB for creating html/pdf exports but do not change how things are displayed in the JupyterLab interface right now. I would recommend searching among [JupyterLab issue tickets on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues) to see if there is one for it (and otherwise opening one).

Comment: It seems to work in the docs: https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html

Comment: Yes, this and HTML export using MyST/Sphinx environment that I mentioned (Jupyter Book uses MyST and then Sphinx to render notebooks as HTML pages). Are you using jupyter{book} too? If yes, then please add it to the tags and edit the question to clarify how you use it.

Comment: I am using JupyterLab exclusively. I'm new to Jupyter. What I want, is to create a presentation with charts and markdown without anyone seeing the code underneath. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Jupyter community then :) I believe the you might be interested in exporting the notebook to Reveal.js slides - first choose slide type in Property Inspector for a few cells and the export it to presentation file (File -> Export Notebook as -> Reveal.js slides). Is this the functionality that you are looking for? If yes, please update the question and I will help you to hide the input/code during export.

Comment: Reveal.js is nice. I would like this question to stand. I will create a new question

Comment: Back to this question - what must I do to turn my notebook into the one demonstrated in the link above (https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to @krassowski 's comment for the answer